# Regex that only returns True on an absolutely blank line without whitespace

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to use `regex` to test if a string is either a `-` followed by some intentional note, or is completely blank without whitespace of any kind.

I tested it on [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) but I don't understand how the `$` symbol doesn't singlehandedly prevent the `\n` character from being a match.

How can I adjust my statement to match my expectations? Thank you in advanced.

```
match(r"^(-.*|)$", "\n") is not None
#returns True

match(r"(^-.*$|^$)", "\n") is not None
#returns True
```

Comment: In terms of why the implementation is designed as it is -- `\n` isn't considered whitespace within a line. Instead, it's the thing that separates that line from the next one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your use of the `$` anchor. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> '$'
>
> Matches the end of the string **or just before the newline at the end of the string**, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a
>   newline.

You have to use `\Z` instead, which matches only at the end of the string:

```
>>> re.match(r'^(-.*)?\Z', '\n') is None
True
```

Or, alternatively, you could drop the anchors and use [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch):

```
>>> re.fullmatch(r'(-.*)?', '\n') is None
True
```

Comment: How would my results be affected if I used `\z` instead of `\Z`?

Comment: @democidist `\z` isn't a valid regex escape sequence, so it'd throw an error if you tried to use it in a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can try matching non-space character after `-`

Regex `^\-\S+` will

```
-a         <-- match
-          <-- no match
-9ddd      <-- match
```

See https://regex101.com/r/56iMem/1